# How to check if the elements of a list are in a set of files?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I have a list of elements, for example,

```
list_elements1 = ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc']
list_elements2 = ['eeee', 'bbbb', 'dddd']
```

I would like to check if the elements of this list occur in a file set. Example:

```
doc1.txt = ['dddd', 'aaaa', 'cccc']
doc2.txt = ['aaaa', 'dddd', 'bbbb']
doc3.txt = ['dddd', 'aaaa', 'cccc', 'bbbb']
```

I would like to present the result in a list of dictionaries:

```
final_list = [list_elements1 = {'aaaa': 3, 'bbbb': 2, 'cccc': 2},
list_elements2 = {'eeee': 0, 'bbbb': 2, 'dddd': 2}]
```

Note that the `'aaaa'` element is three because it occurs in three files and and that `final_list` is a list of dictionaries. The code follows below. The files are in the `dumpfile` directory and with each call to the function `functionCOUNT` each list of elements is passed by parameter:

```
def functionCOUNT(list_elements):
    final_list = []
    file1 = "./dumpfiles/"
    file = os.listdir(file1)
    for i in file:
            #other unnecessary lines have been hidden here
            fp = open(i, "r", -1, 'utf-8')
            elements = fp.readlines()
            element = "".join(str(x) for x in elements)
            element = element.split()
            for j in list_elements:
                if j in element:
                    cont += 1
                    final_list.append({list_elements:{element[j]:cont}})
            fp.close()
```

This line `final_list.append({list_elements:{element[j]:cont}})` contains something wrong, because it does not insert the correct quantity and gives an error. Can anyone help me with this error?

Comment: Can you provide the whole traceback? if any error is occurring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list_elements1 = ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc'] # input

list_elements2 = ['eeee', 'bbbb', 'dddd']

def functionCOUNT(list_elements):

```
docs= [['dddd', 'aaaa', 'cccc'],
       ['aaaa', 'dddd', 'bbbb'],
       ['dddd', 'aaaa', 'cccc', 'bbbb']] # in this case my file is a list of list
final_list = [] 
dict={}# declare de empty dictionary
for i in docs: #for each document(list) in docs(list of lists)
    for j in range(len(list_elements)):# for each element in the input
        if not(list_elements[j] in dict): # create a key for each element in list_element if it doesn´t create yet
            dict[list_elements[j]]=0 # initialize de value for this key
        if list_elements[j] in i:# if the element ein list_elemnets is in i(each document)
            dict[list_elements[j]]=dict[list_elements[j]]+1 # increment de value for this key in dictionay
final_list.append(dict) # add the dictionary at the final list
print(final_list)
```

functionCOUNT(list_elements2) #call of the fuction

#I hope it helps you. :)

Comment: It helped a lot, I appreciate your help! =)